# Meaning of "graduate"

Tags: terminology

I am currently a student in a European university in the fourth year (first year of which is called "master").

On the Internet, it is said undergraduate students to refer to students in a bachelor.

But, what is the exact terminology?
Do we say that a student involved in a master is a graduate student? Then how do we call someone who does have a master's degree (and involved or not in a Ph.D)?

My question may seem unclear but I try to understand the correct use of undergraduate, graduate,... in order to be able to introduce myself correctly and to understand at which level are my interlocutors.